# Grouping XML elements based on a template transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt

**Edit: refactored question and code**

Extending [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316208/grouping-xml-elements-based-on-attributes-with-xslt/11316699#comment14895945_11316699)...

I have an XML feed that represents start and end times of presentation in the format: `2012-06-06 10:45`, with each of those nodes being represented in this manner:

```
<session id="9c4716c71f" name="Session 1" starttime="2012-06-06 10:45" endtime="2012-06-06 12:45" location="" chair="">
  <article code="c1" id="TT-282" type="presentation"></article>
  <article code="c2" id="TT-301" type="presentation"></article>
  ...
</session>
<session id="9c4716c249z" name="Session 2" starttime="2012-06-06 14:45" endtime="2012-06-06 16:45" location="" chair="">
  <article code="c1" id="TT-214" type="presentation"></article>
  <article code="c2" id="TT-328" type="presentation"></article>
  ...
```

In the previous question I only cared about grouping by times, however now I want to group all of these on the date as well (June 6th, 2012).

So, ideally, I would have output that is grouped first by date, and then by time (as I will show in the following bits of code).

I have a template that I apply in order to display that portion:

```
<!-- formatting dateTime -->
<xsl:template name="formatDate">
  <xsl:param name="dateTime" />
  <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($dateTime, ' ')" />
  <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-before($date, '-')" />
  <xsl:variable name="month" select="number(substring-before(substring-after($date, '-'), '-'))" />
  <xsl:variable name="day" select="number(substring-after(substring-after($date, '-'), '-'))" />

  <!-- output -->
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '1'">January</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '2'">February</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '3'">March</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '4'">April</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '5'">May</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '6'">June</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '7'">July</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '8'">August</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '9'">September</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '10'">October</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '11'">November</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = '12'">December</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:value-of select="' '" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$day" />
  <xsl:value-of select="', '" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$year" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- formatting dateTime -->
<xsl:template name="formatTime">
  <xsl:param name="dateTime" />
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($dateTime, ' ')" />
</xsl:template>
```

and I apply it in this manner:

```
<h4>
  <!-- output DD-MM-YYYY -->
  <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="@starttime" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</h4>
```

Here is my current method of grouping.  As can be seen, it groups directly on the unformatted datetime (`2012-06-06 10:45`), but I would like to first group on the formatted date (stored within `$cdate`) and then within `$ctime`.

```
<xsl:template match="session">

  <xsl:variable name="cdate">
    <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
      <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="@starttime" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>


  <xsl:if test='not(preceding-sibling::session[@starttime = current()/@starttime])'>
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="@starttime" /></h2>
    <div><xsl:apply-templates /></div>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="article">
  <b><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></b>
</xsl:template>
```

So, at present I am seeing a list of unique @startime values showing up on the page.
The output that I would really, really love to see (I am still working through the XSLT mindset) is something like this:

```
June 06, 2012
  10:45 - 12:45  |    TT-282
                 |    TT-301
  ----------------------------------
  14:45 - 16:45  |    TT-214
                 |    TT-328

June 07, 2012
  ....
```

I care a little bit less about the direct formatting at this point, but just want to be able to have this two-part grouping that is variable-based.  Any and all help is definitely appreciated.

Comment: again, if you're going to vote to close please at least tell me what's wrong with it...to me its explicitly clear what i want

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 1.0 you can do a two pass transformation using a variable and then an extension function like [`exsl:node-set`](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="temp-doc">
  <!-- now create the nodes here you want to process later on in a second pass -->
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="k2" match="foo" use="bar"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- here we are processing the nodes in the variable obtained from the first pass of prcocesssing -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($temp-doc)//foo[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k2', bar)[1])]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo">...</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is this answer really for the current question? Doesn't seem so.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, but i've ended up refactoring my code a bit and will post a better-formed question with my new code